# Display some text based on specific product attribute value on product page view - magento

Tags: magento-1.7, product

I wrote a little code, but it does not work, what am I doing wrong?

```
        $_product = $this->getProduct();
        $_values = $_product->getAttributeText('artist');
        $filterValue=Array();
        foreach($_values as $_value) {
            $filterValue[]=$_value->getFrontend()->getValue();
            }
            if (in_array("John Coltrane", $filterValue)) {
            echo 'John Coltrane songs'; 
            }
```

- I using this code in product page view (view.phtml).
- Attribute "artist" is multiselect.

I want display text "John Coltrane songs" - if there is a value "John Coltrane" of the attribute "artist".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your multiselect attribute name is artist then use the below code it will work

$_product->getAttributeText('artist');